# C language program that doesn't work?

Tags: c, for-loop

the user enters a secret word and then from the alphabet choses a letter and if the letter is in the secret word it turns into an asterisk. i think the problem is in the two for loops because it does no seem to replace the letter with an asterisk.

```
int main ()
{
  char secretword[20] = {};
  char alphabet[27] = {"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"};
  char guess;
  int i = 0, k = 0;
  int length = 0;

  length = strlen(secretword);

  printf("You Get six chances to guess all of the letters in a phrase\n");
  printf("Enter the secret word/phrase: ");
  scanf("%s", &secretword);
  printf("Past guesses: ");
  printf("%s\n", alphabet);
  printf("Guess a character: ");
  scanf("%s", &guess);

  for(i = 0; i < 27; i++)
  {
    for(k = 0; k < length; k++)
    {
      if(secretword[k] == alphabet[i])
      {
        secretword[k] = '*';
      }
    }
  }

  printf("%s", secretword);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What did you discover when you attempted to debug this?

Comment: He discovered homework is no fun.

Comment: There are only 26 letters in the English alphabet...unless you're including the null character in your alphabet?

Comment: Your inner `for` loop will never run. You've initialized `length` to a char array that is empty, so your loop is `for(k = 0; k < 0; k++)`. Start by fixing that first.

Comment: Hey,still nobody saw the 27 in there.

Comment: @wildplasser 27 allows the null terminator in the string.

Comment: That was cryptic! (but I meant in the "answers", not in the comments)

Comment: @wildplasser you're right - I hadn't seen the 27 in the for loop (which should be 26)

Comment: I have a rule of thumb: every "manifest" constant (other than 0 or 1) in a program is suspect. (and even 0 and 1 can be avoided)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, there is a big logic error. The two for loops:

```
  for(i = 0; i < 27; i++)
  {
    for(k = 0; k < length; k++)
    {
      if(secretword[k] == alphabet[i])
      {
        secretword[k] = '*';
      }
    }
  }
```

Says:

- for all characters in the alphabet,

  - iterate over all characters in the string, and then

    - if that character in the string is equal to the current alphabet character:

      - replace it with an asterisk.

Because you're iterating over the whole alphabet, you'll replace all of the string with '*'s. What you probably want is something like:

```
for(k = 0; k < length; k++)
{
  if(secretword[k] == guess)
  {
    secretword[k] = '*';
  }
}
```

instead.

There are some other problems. This needs to be *after* secretword is read in:

```
 length = strlen(secretword);
```

Otherwise you'll read the length of the uninitalised word. Change it to something like this:

```
 printf("You Get six chances to guess all of the letters in a phrase\n");
 printf("Enter the secret word/phrase: ");
 scanf("%s", &secretword);
 length = strlen(secretword);
```

Also, this:

```
 scanf("%s", &guess);
```

Should probably be:

```
 scanf("%c", &guess);
```

since you're planning to only read a `char` rather than a string.

---

Also, the 27 in this line:

```
char alphabet[27] = {"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"};
```

Is correct, because you want to include the null terminator at the end of the string.

However, this:

```
for(i = 0; i < 27; i++)
```

Will read up to `alphabet[26]`, which will be a `'\0'`. You probably don't want to replace these `'\0'`s in the string (and you won't see any if you're only going up to `strlen(secretword)` characters - since `strlen()` counts up to the first `'\0'`). Changing the loop to only go to 26 characters stops you doing an unnecessary pass over the `secretword`. It should probably be

```
for(i = 0; i < strlen(alphabet); i++)
```

Or, even better (as suggested by wildplasser):

```
char alphabet[] = {"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"}; 

....

for(i = 0; i < sizeof alphabet -1; i++)
```

---

One last thing - your program will crash if you don't have enough space in the `secretword` array to hold the string read in. You can get around this by asking scanf to read only 19 characters:

```
scanf("%19s", &secretword);
```

Note that scanf will terminate the string with a `'\0'`, so `%19s` may put up to 20 bytes in to the string.

Comment: `char alphabet[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";` and `for(i = 0; i < sizeof alphabet -1; i++)` will be cleaner.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken about `scanf`, the format string should be `"%19s"` to allow room for the null-byte.

Answer (score 2):

You set the length variable before secretword is initialized with an actual string so the length will always be zero (or garbage depending on how the compiler decides to initaliaze the variable secretword).

Comment: so i switched out the strlen with just a number and now when it prints the output is all asterisks

Comment: @user1270405 You need to do the strlen after the scanf where you actually put data inside secretword

Answer (score 2):

Try putting `length = strlen(secretword);` after `scanf("%s", &secretword);`. Without entering anything, `strlen()` will return 0, finishing the for-loop immediately.